# How can I reduce the size of my code and get the same result

Tags: c, driver, gpio

Is there a way to get the same result with a smaller size of code in c?

My Function:

```
void PCA9575_set_gpio_level(uint8_t gpio_num, uint8_t level) {
  
  uint8_t reg, data, pin;
  uint8_t buf[1] = {0};
  buf[1] = PCA9575_read_register(OUT0);

  if (gpio_num >= 28 && gpio_num <= 35) {
    reg = OUT0;
    pin = gpio_num - 27;
    if (pin == 3) {
      pin = 4;
    } else if (pin == 4) {
      pin = 8;
    } else if (pin == 5) {
      pin = 16;
    } else if (pin == 6) {
      pin = 32;
    } else if (pin == 7) {
      pin = 64;
    } else if (pin == 8) {
      pin = 128;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    if (level == 1) {
      if (buf[1] == 0) {
        data = pin;
      } else if (buf[1] == 0xFF) {
        data = 0xFF;
      } else {
        data = buf[1] ^ pin;
      }
    } else if (level == 0) {
      if (buf[1] == 0) {
        data = 0;
      } else {
        data = buf[1] ^ pin;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  else if (gpio_num >= 36 && gpio_num <= 43) {
    reg = OUT1;
    pin = gpio_num - 35;
    if (pin == 3) {
      pin = 4;
    } else if (pin == 4) {
      pin = 8;
    } else if (pin == 5) {
      pin = 16;
    } else if (pin == 6) {
      pin = 32;
    } else if (pin == 7) {
      pin = 64;
    } else if (pin == 8) {
      pin = 128;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    if (level == 1) {
      if (buf[1] == 0) {
        data = pin;
      } else {
        data = buf[1] ^ pin;
      }
    } else if (level == 0) {
      if (buf[1] == 0) {
        data = 0;
      } else {
        data = buf[1] ^ pin;
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    return;
  }

  PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, data);
}
```

The buf[1] variable is a value from 00000000 - 11111111 which is based on what has already been set.
The data variable is a value from 00000000 - 11111111 which will set the gpio pins.
The code should read what gpio pins are set and keep them set. Also at the same time set the new desired gpio pin.
GPIO pins are values from 28 - 43.

Comment: Remember that array indexes are *zero* based. Think about that and how you use `buf`. Why is `buf` even an array to begin with?  A single-element array seldom make much sense.

Comment: @Greg Pike The question is off-topic and will be closed.

Comment: Are you aware of what the `<<` operator does? If yes explain what keeps you from using it. If not read up.

Comment: Also, the whole `if (pin == ...)` chain is not needed. What is, for example, `1U << 2`? What is `1U << 3`? Etc.

Comment: using switch instead of if forest can be a huge improvement and also bitwise operations

Comment: I think your question is better suited forhttps://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
void PCA9575_set_gpio_level(uint8_t gpio_num, uint8_t level) 
{
    uint8_t reg, pin;
    uint8_t buf = PCA9575_read_register(OUT0);
    if (gpio_num > 27 && gpio_num < 36) 
    {
        reg = OUT0;
        pin = gpio_num - 27;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (gpio_num > 35 && gpio_num < 44) 
        {
            reg = OUT1;
            pin = gpio_num - 35;
        }
    }
    else return;
    pin = 1 << (pin - 1);
    if(level < 2)
    {
        if(!buf) data = level * pin;
        else if(buf == 0xff && gpio_num < 36) data = 0xff;
        else data = buf ^pin;
    }
    PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, data);
}
```